# How to minimize html from multi div to one div having different href link under each div

Tags: html, angular, typescript

The ngIf's under each div getting link from angular typescript file.Which ever language website i give that language form website should open."don't know number" is coming from the json file of i18n.

```
//ts code
this.url="https://a.es/";

//html code
<div class="a" *ngIf='this.url=="https://a.es/"'>
          <p><a href="https://forms.a.es" target="_blank">{{"dont'know number" | translate}}</a></p>
        </div>
<div class="a" *ngIf='this.url=="https://a.fr/"'>
          <p><a href="https://forms.a.fr" target="_blank">{{"dont'know number" | translate}}</a></p>
        </div>
```

The code should run one div in html.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can just do that:

```
<div class="a">
  <p><a [attr.href]="url" target="_blank">{{"dont'know number" | translate}}</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: If i use your answer then i have to use 10 <p> tags for 10 languages.So,can it reduced more efficiently so this i can use very less number of <p> tags?Actually i am try to minify the HTML file.So if i use 10 <p> tags,the it will be same as using 10 <div> tags.And in this way there will be no reduction of HTML file size.

Comment: @RitwikSarkar hmm I see and how do you get the value of the url ?

Comment: TS CODE->this.url="https://a.es/";<-Here the url is given
if(this.url=="https://a.es/"){
   this.langtag="https://a.es/";
}else if(this.url=="https://a.fr/"){
   this.langtag="https://a.fr/";
}if(this.url=="https://a.es/"){
      this.ab="https://forms.a.es";
}else if(this.url=="https://a.fr/"){
      this.ab="https://forms.a.fr";
}HTML CODE-><div class="a" *ngIf='"langtag/"'>
 <p><a href='"ab"'>{{"dont'know my flight number" | translate}}</a></p>
</div>//main website given by the user,logic is run on the ts file,langtag is rendering,but ab is not rendering.

Comment: HTML CODE-><div class="a" *ngIf='"langtag/"'>
          <p><a [attr.href]="ab" target="_blank">{{"dont'know my number" | translate}}</a></p>
        </div>//I am running this code but it is not rendering ab variable from TS code.

Comment: @RitwikSarkar remove the *ngIf

Comment: OK i understand the *ngIf is not required.When i am removing the *ngIf the output in the browser '"dont'know my number" | translate' link is not working.So,[attr.href]="ab" is not rendering the if else loop from TS file which is supposed give the form link.